# Why does Windows Automatic Updates ignore SQL Server service Packs?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Why does Windows Automatic Updates ignore SQL Server service Packs?

Windows Server 2003 Standard X64 Service Pack 2

No WSUS server in the picture just Automatic Updates enabled.

Default install of SQL Server 2005 Standard and Automatic Updates won't display Service Packs for SQL Server.  It shows all kinds of other critical security updates for the OS, IE, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service packs didn't show up via the web update page until after I installed the .net frame work updates.  Once I did these and rebooted SP3 appeared.

Answer (score 5):

I know this sounds terribly obvious - but are you using Microsoft Update, or Windows Update?  If the latter, you need to enable the Microsoft Update feature that checks for all MS products, not just integral OS components (like IE)

Comment: How do you enable this supposed feature?  There are no additional tabs within Automatic Updates, the only other items are "Windows Update Web Site." which also doesn't detect the SQL Server Service Packs or "Offer Updates again that I've previously Hidden" which is greyed out as I've not hidden any.

Comment: When you first open the Windows Update icon, the IE page you are pushed to should, somewhere, say "Upgrade to Miscorsoft Update Now!" on the page.

If not, try this link on the target machine:

http://update.microsoft.com/microsoftupdate/v6/default.aspx?ln=en-US

Comment: That is where the link that I mentioned above "Windows Update Web Site" takes me and it dosn't detect any SQL Server service Packs...

Comment: Does the Update page for you say Microsoft Update or Windows Update?
http://techrepublic.com.com/i/tr/cms/contentPics/5863098_MicrosoftUpdate_F.gif

Comment: Microsoft and yes I clicked the SQL Server group on the left under Select By Product.
http://update.microsoft.com/windowsupdate/v6/default.aspx?ln=en-us

Comment: It's not that big a deal to get this working, as I can just go manually download SP3 and install it.  It would just be nice if Automatic updates detected these.

Comment: That's odd.  Have you tried running MBSA against that server to see if that can detect the required SQL SP?